# Eclipse: All projects in the workspace start to give An internal error occurred during: "Validating XXXX" NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp

All of a sudden as I accidentally remove a jar file from maven repository .m2 folder(I am not sure it is relevant) and Eclipse complaint about this error message to all projects.

[image]

How can I clean this up?

I can see if I set STS/Eclipse as "Build Automatically" then if I make any change to the application then the project can rebuild the update, but if I choose to "clean.." and make clean build of the whole project then this error start to kick out.

Comment: Just clean the project and restart eclipse. This kinda happens every few days.

Comment: @Navin I can't, that's how I get the error message.

Comment: @Aniket I use maven sync with central server, but rebuild didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you try doing Maven -> Update Selected projects for all projects?

Comment: @mdewitt Yes but still pop the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Close and open the eclipse project. This works for me!

Comment: This was suggested in the comments nearly two years ago.

Comment: Hi. Where is it? I dont see anything related to  : "close project". I see "clean project". In my case , clean is not posible due to error popup. Maven option is not posible due to error popup.  Restart eclipse does not work for me. Only works , close project and reopen it. Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's the same solution: comments are not answers. If this approach provides an actual solution to the question asked, it's correct to post it as an answer, even if someone else first suggested it as a comment. Of course, it's polite to give the commenter the time to post an answer first, but since it's been 2 years...